# How to print index with decreased font size?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print equation on screen and print the indexes with decreased font size.

For example (`i` and `i-1` have smaller font):

[image]

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `maketrans` and `translate`

```
def get_sub(x):
    normal = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-=()"
    sub_s = "ₐ₈CDₑբGₕᵢⱼₖₗₘₙₒₚQᵣₛₜᵤᵥwₓᵧZₐ♭꜀ᑯₑբ₉ₕᵢⱼₖₗₘₙₒₚ૧ᵣₛₜᵤᵥwₓᵧ₂₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₊₋₌₍₎"
    res = x.maketrans(''.join(normal), ''.join(sub_s))
    return x.translate(res)
  
# display subscript
print('A{} = A{} + 10'.format(get_sub('i'),get_sub('i-1')))

#output
Aᵢ = Aᵢ₋₁ + 10
```